# dojo.byId("something").value get script error on IE compatible view

Tags: javascript, spring, internet-explorer, dojo

The same code works for FF and chrome, but IE is unique

the line of code is here:

```
dojo.byId("form_assigned_orders").value = orderIds;
```

simple at it is, just pass an array value to a component. but when I click the save button of the form, I get this error:

```
Message: Unable to set value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined
```

Anyone has an idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of dom element is "form_assigned_orders"?

Comment: I find out that the `form_assigned_orders` element which not generated by dojo correctly. So problem solved. Thanks guys.

Comment: add your answer here this will help others too...